# Обучение нейросети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Я начинающий программист нейросетей. Посмотрел много видео и немного не пойму, как правильно обучать сеть, у меня два варианта ,помогите выбрать.

Есть условно массив, это входные данные, матрица Х скажем так.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [2, 3, 5],
              [3, 2, 1],
              [1, 2, 3],
              [2, 3, 5],
              [3, 2, 1]])
```

Как мне проводить обучение, два варианта:

1. Взять тысяцу раз (эпох) рандомно элемент из выборки и прогнать их через сеть, обратное распространение и тд, потом тоже самое просто уже на новых весах. Получится тысяча рандомных проходов.
2. В каждой эпохе обучать и уточнять веса на каждом элементе из выборки и так к примеру 1000 раз. Получится 6000 проходов.

Какой выбрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант будет бесполезным

> Взять тысяцу раз (эпох) рандомно элемент из выборки и прогнать их через сеть, обратное распространение и тд, потом тоже самое просто уже на новых весах. Получится тысяча рандомных проходов.

Все "знания" нейросети находятся в ее весах. Поэтому если Вы будете брать новые веса, то вы по сути обучение 1000 нейроных сетей по 1 разу, а в этом нет смысла.

Нужно последовательно брать элементы из обучающей выборки и обучать нейронную сеть по х раз. Кол-во раз уже настраивается Вами. Если x будет чересчур большим то нейронная сеть будет "переобучена", если чересчур маленьким то нейросеть не доучится.

Так же могу добавить что x сильно зависит от размеров (кол-ва нейронов) сети. Т.е. чем больше сеть тем больше раз нужно прогонять элемент через нейросеть.

Comment: я там для первого случая имел ввиду, не прям новые веса, а уже уточнённые каждые раз после каждого прохода

Answer (score 2):

**Эпоха** - это когда вся обучающая выборка проходит через нейронную сеть в прямом и обратном направлении 1 раз. По этому в первом варианте это не количество эпох, а просто количество раз сколько нейронная сеть прошла туда обратно с какими-то входными данными.

Как может выглядеть функция обучения для второго варианта (псевдокод):

```
пока эпоха < N
  цикл по обучающей выборке, x = элемент обучающей выборки
    сделать проход по нейронной сети с x на входе
    получить результаты
    изменить веса
```

Как может выглядеть функция обучения для первого варианта (псевдокод):

```
пока эпох < N
  x = случайный элемент из обучающей выборки
  сделать проход по нейронной сети с x на входе
  получить результаты
  изменить веса
```

Если представить, что `x` генерируется по порядку. То есть сначала будет возвращен первый элемент, потом второй, и когда дойдет до конца, то опять первый и так по кругу. То если взять `N = 1000*размер обучающей выборки`, то это будет 1 в 1 второй вариант у которого `N` будет `1000`.

То есть различие первого и второго варианта заключается лишь в том, что в первом, элемент выбирается случайно. Т.к. элементы выбираются случайно, то какой-то элемент будет рассмотрен один раз, какой-то несколько, какой-то может вообще не быть рассмотренным нейронной сетью. Во втором же варианте, каждый элемент будет рассмотрен одинаковое количество раз.

P.s. если для первого варианта `N` большое, то т.к. функция `randint` (отсылка на предыдущий вопрос автора) возвращает псевдослучайные числа, с равномерным распределением. Тогда первый вариант будет отличатся от второго, лишь тем, что порядок рассмотрения элементов случаен (псевдослучаен). А если во втором варианте обучать на случайно перемешанной обучающей выборке, тогда эти варианты можно сказать, что практически одинаковые.